# How to highlight a specific label element in a form with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Need a bit help here.
So I have a form on my WP site.
What I want to achieve is: when the user hovers over an input field (except the submit button), the specific label tag attached to this specific field should be highlighted too.

You can see that for now, I only managed to highlight all of the labels when a hover action over the input occurs. I know that *this* somehow probably plays a role here, but I can't manage to solve this riddle.

Will appreciate any help! Many thanks ahead.

```
<form action="/wordpress/contact/#wpcf7-f137-o1" method="post" 
 class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">

   <div style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="137" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f137-o1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0" />
   </div>

   <p><label> What's your name?*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
     <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" 
     class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" 
     aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" />
    </span></label>
   </p>

   <p><label> What's your email address?*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
     <input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" 
      class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-
      as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-
      invalid="false" />
    </span></label>
   </p>

   <p><label> Please, leave a message!*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea 
     name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control 
     wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" 
     aria-invalid="false"></textarea>
    </span></label>
   </p>

 <p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-
  submit" /></p>
 <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
</form>


jQuery(function(){
  jQuery(".wpcf7-text").mouseenter(function(){
  jQuery(".wpcf7-form").find("label").css({ 'color': '#1e1e1e'});
 });
  jQuery(".wpcf7-text").mouseleave(function(){
  jQuery(".wpcf7-form").find("label").css({ 'color': '#cacaca'});
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use **closest("label")**
>   `$(this).closest("label").css({ 'color':'#1e1e1e'});`

```js
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery(".wpcf7-text").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).closest("label").css({ 'color': '#1e1e1e'});
 });
  jQuery(".wpcf7-text").mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).closest("label").css({ 'color': '#cacaca'});
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/wordpress/contact/#wpcf7-f137-o1" method="post" 
 class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">

   <div style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="137" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f137-o1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0" />
   </div>

   <p><label> What's your name?*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
     <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" 
     class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" 
     aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" />
    </span></label>
   </p>

   <p><label> What's your email address?*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
     <input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" 
      class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-
      as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-
      invalid="false" />
    </span></label>
   </p>

   <p><label> Please, leave a message!*<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea 
     name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control 
     wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" 
     aria-invalid="false"></textarea>
    </span></label>
   </p>

 <p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-
  submit" /></p>
 <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. That helped a lot! Appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of jQuery function `closest()`.

```
jQuery(".wpcf7-text").closest("label").css({ 'color': '#1e1e1e'});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` will refer to the element that you are hovering over, and you can use the `closest()` to find a parent that matches the selector.

```
jQuery(this).closest("label").css({ 'color': '#1e1e1e'});
```

You could also do this with css by setting a rule for the hover state of some element that wraps your field and label.

```
p:hover label {
  color: #1e1e1e;
}
```